# Optimal setup for Doxygen in a large multi-application COM project

Tags: c++, doxygen

A system has up to 100 VC++ projects, each spitting out a DLL or EXE. In addition there are many COM components with IDL and generated .h/.c files.

What's 'the right way' or at least a good way to organise this with Doxygen? One overall doxy project or one per project/solution? And what's the right way to handle COM, which has generated code and a lot of 'fluff' that will bloat generated HTML files.

Comment: I found some crossover with this, though it's not a total duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2908086/how-to-manage-a-doxygen-project-with-multiple-libraries

Answer (score 1):

I haven't had a chance to try this out yet, but doxygen has the ability to [link to external documentation](http://www.doxygen.nl/manual/external.html).  I would probably do separate projects, and experiment with using the external linking.  Otherwise, with the large number of projects you describe, a single doxygen build could take a very, very long time.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want certain files to be included in your Doxygen output, you can use the EXCLUDE_PATTERNS directive.  One project I work on uses

```
EXCLUDE_PATTERNS = */test/*
```

to avoid including our unit test classes in the Doxygen output.  If your autogenerated COM files have any sort of pattern to them, you could exclude them this way.

Answer (score 0):

I opted for several separate doxygen builds as follows:

- Build top-level lib for main application, not including libraries
- Build separate "libs" docs for each library
- Optionally build a "global" doxygen build with everything
- Optionally build the libs with "Internal" switch turned on.
- All output was contained in a single Doxygen folder (`Doxygen\application`, `Doxyge\Lib1...`)
- Use a The top-level lib build uses a "mainpage" with links to the library functions, 
  e.g.  `<a href="../_Lib1/html/index.html">Lib #1</a>`
- The libs have a mainpage with a link back to the top-level lib mainpage: 
  e.g. `href="../../_TopLevel/html/index.html"`

Not sure about the COM stuff...

Steve